# Logic App how to use http request chunking to process large files

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement to move files from Azure blob storage to SharePoint.

The storage account is protected by firewall rules so I cannot use the built-in connectors. I am using managed identities and the http request action to overcome this as per MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=consumption#access-blob-storage-with-managed-identities

And I have the process working for a small test file so I have resolved all connectivity authentication issues etc. But I want to be sure if I need to move a large file it will be able to process it. (I am testing with a 500Mb file)

I am using the get blob rest API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob

In the logic app http action request header I have enabled "content transfer - allow chunking" as MS docs suggest here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#set-up-chunking-over-http

I have used Range/x-ms-range : bytes=255-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-blob-service-operations

I have tried using the pagination setting also.

None of this seems to work and I keep getting an exception.
`BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600.'.`

I dont think I am hitting a Logic App service limitation because we move large files in other processes. So I think I am not doing something correctly with the chunking. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if there's a built in chunk in Azure Storage Connector, but one thing I did in the past and worked for me, I've created and Azure Function which was part of my Logic Apps Workflow and was responsible to chunk the file into smaller files.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I suspect you'd need the chunk size sent to the SPO REST API to match the chunk size of the Azure Storage GET, which I believe is 50MB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1200266/the-template-language-function-body-cannot-be-used